# DataGridView Column Header to include text AND check box

Tags: c#, .net, checkbox, datagridview, columnheader

I have two columns of check boxes for 'Build' and 'Publish'. I want each of the headers to display 'Build [ ]" and 'Publish [ ]", where [ ] is a check box that allow the user to select or deselect all check boxes in the respective column. **PRIORITY:** How can I achieve this without creating new classes or adding images? **LAST RESORT:** If this is not possible, can you guide me to construct the appropriate classes? Thanks in advance!

Comment: See [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/9a93d028-8dcb-4cfa-bf58-34086b16c9fe/how-to-use-controls-in-the-column-headers-of-a-datagridview?forum=winformsdatacontrols)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two regular `CheckBoxes` and add them to the `DataGridView`:

```
cbx_Build.Parent = dataGridView1;
cbx_Build.Location = new Point(0, 3);
cbx_Build.BackColor = SystemColors.Window;
cbx_Build.AutoSize = false;

cbx_Publish.Parent = dataGridView1;
cbx_Publish.Location = new Point(0, 3);
cbx_Publish.BackColor = SystemColors.Window;    
cbx_Publish.AutoSize = false;
```

To keep them positioned in the ColumnHeaders use code like this:

```
dataGridView1.CellPainting += dataGridView1_CellPainting;  


void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.ColumnIndex == BuildIndex && e.RowIndex == 0) cbx_Build.Left = e.CellBounds.Left;
  if (e.ColumnIndex == PubIndex && e.RowIndex == 0) cbx_Publish.Left = e.CellBounds.Left;
}
```

Use appropriate indices to meet your columns and offsets to place them a little more to the right, if needed.

You will have to implement your logic to prevent value changes in the DGV as you normally would, e.g. in the `Validating` event..

Update:

This event is probably a good or even better alternative as it doesn't get called so often; it'll do, at least if you only need to adapt the position after the user changes the column widths:

```
private void dataGridView1_ColumnWidthChanged(object sender, DataGridViewColumnEventArgs e)
{
   cbx_Build.Left = dataGridView1.Columns[BuildIndex].HeaderCell.ContentBounds.Left;
   cbx_Publish.Left = dataGridView1.Columns[PubIndex].HeaderCell.ContentBounds.Left;
}
```

If columns can also be deleted, added or reordered these events would also have to be scripted: `ColumnRemoved, ColumnAdded, ColumnDisplayIndexChanged`. All work with the above 2 lines.

Comment: Thanks! Currently trying this out! What is "Build" and "Publish" in the method? The check boxes?

Comment: sorry, just typos ;-)

Comment: I did used Color.Transparent, but it looks good so far! Thank you so much! How would I be able to position it with Build/Publish such that if I resize the columns, the check boxes will go with it?

Comment: I have added an `AutoSize = false` to allow for changing their width independent of theit Text. You need to decide though, which do you want: Size the TB with the column : `cbx_Build.Width = e.CellBounds.Width;` or should the Column go with the TextBox : `dataGridView1.Columns[1].Width = checkBox1.Width + 3;` Put one in the setup code, the other in the CellPainting..

Comment: This doesn't change anything. The check box is still positioned in the same place it was initialized. While I resize the columns, they still stay in the spot and not with the respective columns.

Comment: The last comment was about sizes. Positions should work anayway: Each checkbox ought to move with the column its index refers to. Have you hooked up the dataGridView1_CellPainting event and set the two indices right??

Comment: I put the event handler after dynamically creating my columns. Indices are set correctly in the method. Break point does stop at the event handler, but it does not stop inside the method called by the event handler. Why is that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61293/discussion-between-taw-and-susieloo).